# What's the significance of 4294967087 as an argument limit to Racket's (random) function?

Tags: racket

When generating random integers in Racket using the [random](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._random%29%29) function, Racket requires the argument to be a number between `1` and `4294967087`. I was just wondering, where does that **4294967087** number come from, and why is it the maximum random number that Racket can generate?

It's close, but not exactly equal, to the maximum value of an unsigned 32-bit integer (4294967295). I assume there must be some reason why such a specific number was chosen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the largest [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime) that is still smaller than 2<sup>32</sup>-1. It is part of the original implementation of the MRG32k3a algorithm by Pierre L'Ecuyer.

The significance of this number is explained in his paper *"Good Parameter Sets for Combined Multiple Recursive Random Number Generators"*, which is available on the [papers website of L'Ecuyer](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/papers.html) (as a postscript file), and as a PDF at http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.47.1.159 . The reference implementation of the MRG32k3a algorithm is also available there: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/combmrg2.c

In this paper, L'Ecuyer analyzed multiple recursive random number generators and did exhaustive searches for parameter sets that caused the generators to have desirable properties: Long period, good distribution of numbers, efficient implementation...

The value in question (which is referred to as 2<sup>31</sup>-209 in the paper) is part of a parameter set of the MRG32k3a algorithm that has these properties.

<sub>(but admittedly, I didn't do the maths...)</sub>

Comment: For comparison: https://github.com/racket/srfi/blob/master/srfi-lib/srfi/27/random-bits.rkt

Answer (score 2):

It is the largest *safe* prime less than 2^32.  They use this number because that gives their pseudo-random number generator the largest possible period.

A safe prime number *p* is a prime for which (*p* - 1)/2 also is prime. This *other* prime is called a *[Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime)*.